# In order to save browser memory, should I destroy bootstrap tooltips array after I rendered new tooltips?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

*I apologize if it is a duplicate question, but I googled first without getting a useful answer.*

#### Scenary

I was doing a search results display work, and every search result has a button that renders tooltips, here is the simplified code, they are already working fine for me:

```js
let searchAndDisplayResults = (function () {
    let tooltips;
    return (key) => {
        // search results container
        let searchContainer = $('.search-results-container');
        // clear elements first
        searchContainer.html('');
        // get search results information array
        let searchedResultsArray = getSearchedResults(key);
        // render search results to page(simplified)
        searchedResultsArray.forEach((ele) => {
              searchContainer.append(`<div>${ele}</div><i class='bi-plus' data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Some hint for this button"></i>`);
        }
        // enable tooltip
        tooltips = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')).map(tooltipTriggerEl => { return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl) });
    }
})();
```

Note: the code that enables tooltips above is from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere).
Every time new search key was passed into the function, old search results' elements will be destroyed and new search results will be re-rendered, but it seems it remains variable `tooltips` not to delete every time search results were re-rendered.

#### Question

So in order to save browser memory consuming, I wonder if I need to delete tooltips array everytime search results were re-rendered?
For example, should I use code like this below to destroy variable `tooltips` everytime new search results to be rendered?

```js
if (tooltips != null) {
    for (let tooltip of tooltips) {
        delete tooltip;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to. Doing `tooltips = something` will remove the reference from the old `tooltips` array. As long as there aren't any other references to `tooltips`, it will be garbage collected.